# Elo rating software with automatic random matchups

Tags: software, programming, elo

This question is not about chess per se, but I am looking for a software that could generate random matchups through a list of 200ish options/people, then I could choose the winner and it would rank the outcomes with Elo rating (or something similar that would also work).

I'm currently using EloRater, but I have to manually generate random numbers from an external source to then create the matchups, scroll down through the list, find them, choose the winner, etc.  I am doing simulations and I need to do many, many matchups from a list. Thus, something that is user-friendly and speeds up the process would greatly help.

I think such software probably exists for chess. Does anyone of anything that could help me?

Comment: FIDE approved pairing systems have to be reproducible (for the obvious reason of wanting to prevent cheating in the pairings, particularly with respect to title norms). Hence there is no incentive to produce such software.

Comment: You could try this famous chess pairing program >swiss-manager.at/

Comment: It is very easy to write.  Not that hard to do manually.  But whatever your results will be meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know elorater but there is likely a way through the opsys to randomly pick (that part is easy) players to match and then insert them automatically into elorater instead of typing them in.  If they have a way to import tournament results you might be able to automate it even easier.  Just create all the random matchups you want and then submit it for rating.